# uploading image from imageview to server

Tags: android, file-upload, retrofit

I am attempting to upload an image from an android application to the server. I am calling the upload function and trying to get the image from ImageVeiw but no success. The image is set on the ImageVeiw from the gallery or camera.
Unable to get the file to send to the server

This is my code that I am using to set image from camera and gallery.

```
if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST & resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Log.d("camera/gallery", "camera");
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            profilePicture.setImageBitmap(photo);
        } else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Log.d("camera/gallery", "gallery");

//            get image from gallery
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap loadedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
//            check orientation of image and rotate if required
            ExifInterface exifInterface = null;
            try{
              File pictureFile = new File(picturePath);
              exifInterface = new ExifInterface(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int orientation = exifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;

            if(exifInterface != null){
                orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            }

            switch(orientation){
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    loadedBitmap = rotateBitmap(loadedBitmap, 90);
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    loadedBitmap = rotateBitmap(loadedBitmap, 180);
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    loadedBitmap = rotateBitmap(loadedBitmap, 270);
                    break;

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                    loadedBitmap = flipBitmap(loadedBitmap, true, false);

                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                    loadedBitmap = flipBitmap(loadedBitmap, false, true);

                default:
                    loadedBitmap =  loadedBitmap;
            }
//            set image to ImageView
            profilePicture.setImageBitmap(loadedBitmap);
        }
```

I am able to get the bitmap image and trying to save it to the file. I am later trying to retrieve the same file and upload it to the server using retrofit

I am getting this error from retrofit on failure

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/data/user/0/com.example.fileuploaddemo/files/cleaton_profile_20191023T111341.png (No such file or directory)
```

Code for storing and retrieving the file and send the image file

```
public void uploadProfileImage(){

        Uri fileUri = getSelectedFile();
        if(Uri.EMPTY.equals(fileUri)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exception Occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            File originalFile = FileUtils.getFile(fileUri.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "in upload"+originalFile.getAbsolutePath());

            RequestBody filePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), originalFile);
            MultipartBody.Part file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", originalFile.getName(), filePart);

            RequestBody modePart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, "profilepicture");

            APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
            apiInterface.uploadPhoto(file, modePart).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public Uri getSelectedFile(){
        try{
            String username = "cleaton";

//            get bitmap from image set on  imageview and convert to byte array
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) profilePicture.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, byteArrayOutputStream);
            byte[] bitmapdata = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
            String timeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), username+"_profile_"+timeStamp+".png");

//            insert byte array into file output stream with name
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(username+"_profile_"+timeStamp+".png", MODE_PRIVATE);
            fileOutputStream.write(bitmapdata);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();

            File profileImageFile =  new File(file.getAbsolutePath());
            Log.d(TAG, "file retrieve"+profileImageFile);
            Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(profileImageFile);
            Log.d(TAG, "file Uri"+fileUri);
            return fileUri;

        } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and code of your setting image to imageview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expound on Webfreak's answer:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Once the `Bitmap` is retrieved, you can create a byte stream from which you can read the bytes and send those to your network socket by using a method similar to those below. Without knowing your upload method I am not sure if this is sufficient.

```
 private InputStream getBitmapInputStream(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(getCompressionFormat(options), 100 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);
    }

    private Bitmap.CompressFormat getCompressionFormat(BitmapFactory.Options options) {
        if (options == null || options.outMimeType == null) return Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG;

        if (options.outMimeType.endsWith("/png")) {
            return Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG;
        } else if (options.outMimeType.endsWith("/webp")) {
            return Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP;
        } else {
            return Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Great help. I have added the next step with the error that is being received

Answer (score 0):

Fist you need to get the bitmap from Imageview:

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Once you have bitmap, you can upload it to server.